# How to hide the arrow buttons in a JScrollBar

Tags: java, swing, awt, jscrollpane

I need to hide the arrow buttons of [`java.awt.Scrollbar(VERTICAL)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Scrollbar.html) in an AWT application.
Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

I saw an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786886/remove-arrows-from-swing-scrollbar-in-jscrollpane), but the code just hides the buttons. The vacant space for the buttons still remains; it is not occupied by the scroll bar.

To be more exact, here is the screenshot of what I should achieve. I am not sure which direction to go about it.

Update : I was looking for a solution in AWT. But now I am open to suggestions in Swing as well.

[image: desired effect]

Comment: Unlike Swing, AWT components don't have a [pluggable look & feel](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/architecture/#pluggable). Which do you need, AWT or Swing?

Comment: Is the `Scrollbar` used for value selection or as part of a `ScrollPane`? Consider posing an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows what you've tried.

Comment: It will go with a ScrollPane.

Comment: Also I don't have anything coded for the scroll bar yet. So wont be be to provide a sscce

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this.. it replaces the regular buttons on the Vertical ScrollBar with buttons that are 0x0 in size.

It does limit your look and feel though :(

```
JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(mainPane);
scroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
// ... etc
scroller.getVerticalScrollBar().setUI(new BasicScrollBarUI()
    {   
        @Override
        protected JButton createDecreaseButton(int orientation) {
            return createZeroButton();
        }

        @Override    
        protected JButton createIncreaseButton(int orientation) {
            return createZeroButton();
        }

        private JButton createZeroButton() {
            JButton jbutton = new JButton();
            jbutton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
            jbutton.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
            jbutton.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
            return jbutton;
        }
    });
```

**Update:** sorry, this is a swing solution

Answer (score 3):

Using [Nimbus Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html) you can use this to remove the arrow buttons:

```
    UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put(
        "ScrollBar:\"ScrollBar.button\".size", 0);
    UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put(
        "ScrollBar.decrementButtonGap", 0);
    UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put(
        "ScrollBar.incrementButtonGap", 0);
```

Here is a full example:

[image]

```
public class ScrollDemo extends JFrame {

    public ScrollDemo() {

        String[] columnNames = {"Column"};
        Object[][] data = {
                {"A"},{"B"},{"C"},{"D"},{"E"},{"F"},
                {"A"},{"B"},{"C"},{"D"},{"E"},{"F"},
                {"A"},{"B"},{"C"},{"D"},{"E"},{"F"},
                {"A"},{"B"},{"C"},{"D"},{"E"},{"F"},
                {"A"},{"B"},{"C"},{"D"},{"E"},{"F"},
        };

        add(new JScrollPane(new JTable(data, columnNames)));
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // No Nimbus
                }
                UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put(
                        "ScrollBar:ScrollBarThumb[Enabled].backgroundPainter",
                        new FillPainter(new Color(127, 169, 191)));
                UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put(
                        "ScrollBar:ScrollBarThumb[MouseOver].backgroundPainter",
                        new FillPainter(new Color(127, 169, 191)));
                UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put(
                        "ScrollBar:ScrollBarTrack[Enabled].backgroundPainter",
                        new FillPainter(new Color(190, 212, 223)));

                UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put(
                        "ScrollBar:\"ScrollBar.button\".size", 0);
                UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put(
                        "ScrollBar.decrementButtonGap", 0);
                UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put(
                        "ScrollBar.incrementButtonGap", 0);

                new ScrollDemo();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Code for the `Painter` used:

```
public class FillPainter implements Painter<JComponent> {

    private final Color color;

    public FillPainter(Color c) { color = c; }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics2D g, JComponent object, int width, int height) {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width-1, height-1);
    }

}
```

Comment: once time one man said `I think the only way to go is to stop using Nimbus`, hmmm nice progress +1