# How to draw a JPanel as a Nimbus JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, nimbus

In Nimbus look and feel JButtons have a very tidy and accurate look, with rounded border and nice background. 
I'd like to render a JPanel with the very same look (obviously it won't have pressed state etc). 
What are my options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to get "Button look" on a JPanel is probably by extending the `JPanel` and override `paintComponent`.

Here is the Nimbus `JButton` look:

[image]

And here is my implementation of a similar look on a `JPanel` (I added an empty border around for showing this example, and the corners are not translucent):

[image]

Here is my code (using [gradients](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/strokeandfill.html)):

```
public class ColorDemo extends JPanel {

    private final int gradientSize = 18;
    private final Color lighterColor = new Color(250, 250, 250);
    private final Color darkerColor = new Color(225, 225, 230);
    private final Color edgeColor = new Color(140, 145, 145);
    private final Stroke edgeStroke = new BasicStroke(1);
    private final GradientPaint upperGradient = new GradientPaint(
            0, 0, lighterColor,
            0, gradientSize, darkerColor);


    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        GradientPaint lowerGradient = new GradientPaint(
                0, getHeight()-gradientSize-1, darkerColor,
                0, getHeight(), lighterColor);
        g2.setPaint(upperGradient);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1 , gradientSize);
        g2.setPaint(darkerColor);
        g2.fillRect(0, gradientSize, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-gradientSize-1);
        g2.setPaint(lowerGradient);
        g2.fillRect(0, getHeight()-gradientSize, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1);
        g2.setStroke(edgeStroke);
        g2.setPaint(edgeColor);
        g2.drawRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1,
                               gradientSize/2, gradientSize/2);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here is an improved `paintComponent` method by *AgostinoX* that solved the *corner issue* in my code.

```
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALI‌​AS_ON);
        float gradientPerc = (float)gradientSize/getHeight();
        LinearGradientPaint lgp = new LinearGradientPaint(0,0,0,getHeight()-1,
           new float[] {0, gradientPerc, 1-gradientPerc, 1f},
           new Color[] {lighterColor, darkerColor, darkerColor, lighterColor});
        g2.setPaint(lgp);
        g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1,
            gradientSize, gradientSize);
        g2.setColor(edgeColor);
        g2.setStroke(edgeStroke);
        g.drawRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1,
            gradientSize, gradientSize);
    }
```

See also my answer to [How to hide the arrow buttons in a JScrollBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633354/how-to-hide-the-arrow-buttons-in-a-jscrollbar/8273197#8273197) on how you can customize the look and feel for Nimbus. And see the [Nimbus defaults](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html#primary) for colors and painters.

Comment: ok, i had a look to that question, it's very intresting; for the border, have you an idea where to get one similar to the one assigned to buttons?

Comment: @AgostinoX: I think there is no easy way to get the same look. You have to override `paintComponent` in the `JPanel` and draw your own gradients.

Comment: great job! The only thing i don't like is that the way you draw gradients, you fill the little corners out of the round border too. it is visible if you use a gradientSize>20. I've tried to improve this (good) solution, and come out with a multi-stop gradient, that simplifies the implementation as well. You find it in  my next comment, it is a drop-in replacement for the paint method and replaces just the fillRect calls with a single call to fillRoundRect. Since the answer is yours, if you'd like to do this "improvement", then i will be happier to accept your answer :-).

Comment: Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
float gradientPerc = (float)gradientSize/getHeight();
LinearGradientPaint lgp = new LinearGradientPaint(0,0,0,getHeight()-1,
new float[] {0, gradientPerc, 1-gradientPerc, 1f},
new Color[] {lighterColor, darkerColor, darkerColor, lighterColor});
g2.setPaint(lgp);
g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1, gradientSize, gradientSize);
g2.setColor(edgeColor);
g2.setStroke(edgeStroke);
g.drawRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1, gradientSize,gradientSize);

Comment: @AgostinoX: Great job! I updated my answer and added your code.